# using shiny dateRangeInput to set axis limits in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm working on a R/shiny application that uses output from a dateRangeInput to set x axis limits in a ggplot2 plot. Subsetting the data using the dateRangeInput works fine, but I can't get scale_x_date (or scale_x_continuous or scale_x_datetime) to recognize the dates returned by dateRangeInput. I've tried using format(), as.Date, as.POSIXct, but haven't had any luck. Whether I try to convert the output of dateRangeInput or not I get:

```
Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

Here's a (hopefully) reproducible example of my problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tp_date_pressed <- as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-01", "2016-03-01"))
sigma <- c(1, 1.5)
data <- data.frame(tp_date_pressed, sigma)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dateRangeInput('date',
        label = 'Date Range',
        start = Sys.Date() - 180, 
        end = Sys.Date(),
        max = Sys.Date()
    ),
    plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  subData <- reactive({
    data %>%
      filter(
        as.Date(tp_date_pressed) >= as.Date(input$date[1]),
        as.Date(tp_date_pressed) <= as.Date(input$date[2])
      )
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(subData(), aes(tp_date_pressed, sigma)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_x_date(limits = input$date)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your original `data`; you used POSIXct when ggplot expects a Date object. If you change it to

```
tp_date_pressed <- as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-03-01"))
```

Note that there's on more problem as [scale_x_date](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html) expects two values for limits. Make sure to change this to

```
scale_x_date(limits = c(input$date[1], input$date[2]))
```

And thanks for the nice reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks John! I had been banging my head against using input$date in scale_x_date because ggplot magically does the right thing when tp_date_pressed is fed in as POSIXct. It never occurred to me that the axis data and axis limits would need to be the same object type!